# Chess c++ console game, differentiate white from black pieces

Tags: c++, console, chess

I am coding a chess console game in c++ as a task in our Programming class. I already made the print function and the input for moving the pieces which functions fine.

Now is the time to make the functions that check if a move is valid or not. And I already have a problem to try and differentiate black pieces from white pieces.

The first move can only be done by white, since white always starts.

So I made a struct of all the pieces:

```
struct chesspiece
{
    string pieceName;
    char pieceColor;
    int pieceValue;
};
```

My output on the console is a string array:

```
const int ROWS = 8;
const int COLS = 8;

string chessboard[ROWS][COLS] = 
{
    chessPiece.pieceName etc.
};
```

Now I am trying to make a function that checks if the first moved piece is white or not, but I can't find the connection between the struct and the string array since the string array only has chessPiece.pieceName in it and not the actual pieceColor variable. Could a struct array be better for building this up or is there something else?

Comment: This is what I consider as design - thinking how to model your problem in data structures. Computer or not - some designs are considered as better some not. Some designs are considered as better by one and not by others. Concerning software, good design solves the problem in an elegant way without any needless details. There are books about design that are not easy to read... (Not that helpful isn't it?) ;-)

Comment: How do you distinguish the colors when you print the board?

Answer (score 0):

Why not include the color of a piece in its name? Even better, use an enum instead of strings; something like that:

```
enum {
    Empty,
    WhitePawn, WhiteRook, WhiteKnight, ...
    BlackPawn, ...
};
```

Or you could even use the symbols representing each piece, if you feel like it can be understood easily (those symbols are well known to chess players).

```
enum {
    Empty,
    WP, WR, WN, ...
    BP, ...
};
```